# Advanced query with mysql: variables/subqueries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

I want to get the latest 5 messages in the inbox.
To get the 5 latest IDs i need to use this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(id)
FROM 
    samtaler
WHERE 
    brukerid_mottaker = 1 
GROUP BY brukerid_avsender
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This return the correct ID's I need. But in the same query i want to select data from the same table, the row that got the id that returned from this query above.

I have tried out some things, variables and self-join but no luck:

```
select 
    p2.title, 
    p2.message,
    @a:=max(p1.id)
from 
    samtaler p1
    join samtaler p2
    on (@a = p2.id)
where
    p2.brukerid_mottaker = 1 
group by p2.brukerid_avsender
order by p2.id DESC
limit 5
```

Why isnt this working?

This is the current data in the database: [image]

I want to return in this case, row 13 and 4. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join against a subquery, instead of a plain self join.  An `IN()` clause won't work since `LIMIT` cannot be used inside an `IN()`.  It should work in the joined subquery though:

```
SELECT
  p1.title,
  p1.message,
  p2.id
FROM 
  samtaler p1
  JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id
    FROM 
        samtaler
    WHERE 
        brukerid_mottaker = 1 
    GROUP BY brukerid_avsender
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 5
  ) p2 ON p1.id = p2.id
```

By this method, there is no need for variables.